# The cause of SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in a JavaScript conditional statement based on the length of a string

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-statements

I've created a simple if/else statement like so :

```
var myName = ["Mark"];

if myName.length <= 3;

{

    console.log("It's not true");

}
else 
{

    console.log("Variable consists of" myName.length);
    console.log("I finished my first course".substring(0,26));

}
```

Unfortunately, the console returns this error : SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I've tried to add square brackets to var myName = "Mark"; but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
var myName = ["Mark"]
```

you are assiging an array to the `myName`, which is not what you want in this case:

```
var myName = "Mark"
```

You have to use parentheses around the if-condition. Also the semicolon is wrong:

```
if (myName.length <= 3){
     ...
}
```

In the else-block you've got the first statement wrong.
You have to use + to concatenate the arguments that you want to print:

```
console.log("Variable consists of" + myName.length);
```

Comment: I wanted to ask about one more little thing. The part where there is : 

    console.log("Variable consists of" + myName.length);

has a semicolon at the end, right after the bracket. I would like to ask why here it has that semicolon and in 'if' statement you said to actually get rid of that semicolon there. Thanks !

Comment: `console.log()` is a function call, and function calls are ended by a semicolon. If is not a function call, it's a keywordthat starts a new scope/block of statements. Short: It's the language's syntax.